# How to study for Adobe Photoshop ACE exam?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm planing to take the Adobe Photoshop ACE certification. I would like to know if is there any specific material and what is the recommended approach to study for the exam?

Comment: I'd say that the prep guide is a pretty good source. It can be found here in the middle: http://www.adobe.com/support/certification/exams/ Would be a good idea to read through the checklist in it as well as doing everything in photoshop that the prep guide covers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Adobe [software] Classroom in a Book* series from PeachPit Press will cover everything that could possibly be asked. YEs, its boring, dry, and hard to get through. But it's a lifesaver if there's an area of the app you don't use regularly.

The [Prep guides](http://www.adobe.com/support/certification/exams/) are a good primer but not really detailed.

[ExamAids.com](http://www.examaids.com) has some decent practice exams. The questions aren't always close, and you shouldn't take the questions as being anything directly associated with the actual tests. Although, I understand the practice questions are, for the most part, written by those who have passed the tests. However, the style of questions are very similar and that's where the examaids can really be helpful.

Comment: I second Classroom in a Book on general principle. Excellent series.